# adding on_click methods to buttons created with ipywidgets

Tags: python, button, onclick, grid, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets to create a dashboard.

I create a bunch of buttons using a loop:

```
from ipywidgets import GridspecLayout

grid = GridspecLayout(4, 3)
def create_expanded_button(description, button_style):
    return Button(description=description, button_style=button_style, layout=Layout(height='auto', width='auto'))


for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        grid[i, j] = create_expanded_button('Button {} - {}'.format(i, j), 'warning')
grid
```

This is the code in the documentation.
With such a code you create a dashboard with 16 buttons:

[image]

The question is what is the strategy as to how to handle every on_click methods of the buttons since all the buttons are called the same.
Do the buttons have a kind of 'id'?

imagine that by clicking every button I want to fetch a particular data online. how to proceed?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def on_btn_click(btn):
    if btn.description == 'Button 0 - 0':
        # do something on Button 0 - 0 click
    elif btn.description == 'Button 0 - 1':
        # do something on Button 0 - 1 click
    ...


for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        grid[i,j].on_click(on_btn_click)
```

Comment: but when I code the method on_btn_click how do I know which button is clicked? imagine that when clicking the first upper left button I want that a=1 and when I click second button of first row a=2. ?

Comment: for instance a real case would be reading data from api, calling a different API reading for instance stock values depending on the button clicked.

Comment: You can get the informations passed by the btn arg, then decide what to do. If you can't distinguish these buttons by the information of each button, then you can write 12 different on_click methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining your APIs and calling functions first, then iterating through those creating buttons?

```py
from ipywidgets import GridspecLayout, Button

grid = GridspecLayout(3, 1)

def call_api_1(button):
    print('calling_api_1')

def call_api_2(button):
    print('calling_api_2')

def call_api_3(button):
    print('calling_api_3')

api_dict = {
    'API 1': call_api_1,
    'API 2': call_api_2,
    'API 3': call_api_3,
}

for index, (api_name, func) in enumerate(api_dict.items()):
    button = Button(description = api_name)
    button.on_click(func)
    grid[index,0] = button

grid
```